# imacros javascript function loop not working

Tags: javascript, imacros

function **master** will only loop twice no matter what number i set the function parameter **loopTest** to. What am i doing wrong?

```
function master(loopTest){

for (i = 1; i <= loopTest; i++){
iimPlay("CODE:URL GOTO=imacros://run/?m=Testing.js");
}

}

master(8);
```

Answer (score 1):

After your `iimPlay("...")` I added the line `iimPlayCode("WAIT SECONDS=1");` and it works as needed.